# How to do horizontal box plot, using HighCharts, without inverted?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, boxplot

I need to create box plot using HighCharts. The box plot must be horizontaly placed. Is there a way to accomplish this, without using inverted?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/m4s0189f/11/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'boxplot',
        inverted: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Box Plot Example'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1'],
        title: {
            text: 'Experiment No.'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Observations',
        data: [
            [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
        ],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
    }]

});
```

Comment: Hi @Georgi Asparuhov, I am afraid that it can be the only way. Why don't you like to use `inverted` option?

Comment: I am trying to have horizontal boxplot and vertical columns at the same time in one chart. And when using inverted for the boxplot it is not possible to have the vertical columns.

Comment: If you want to have the same scale, you can use `xrange` series type. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pntd4vwm/